How to create customized frame environment with an additional setting?
I have a beamer document:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}
\setlength{\parskip}{\fill}

We have A.
We have B.

\end{frame}

\end{document}

I would like to create \begin{myframe}{}...\end{myframe} where \setlength{\parskip}{\fill} is enabled. Could you elaborate on how to do so?

Update: In this question, I want to create a new frame environment. In the previous question, I want to create a new option for the existing frame environment.

\documentclass{beamer}

\newenvironment{badidea}[1]
     {\begin{frame}[environment=badidea]
         \setlength{\parskip}{\fill}
         \frametitle{#1}}
     {\end{frame}}

\begin{document}

\begin{badidea}{Bad idea}
  abc
\end{badidea}

\end{document}


